# spring-xd running via eclipse documentation

Tags: spring-xd

I have been able to start the spring-xd single node by running the SingleNodeApplication via eclipse however when I try to browser to admin application it gives 403 error. Before I go ahead and spend time investigating the cause of it I would like to know what practice/process does spring-xd team uses to run the spring-xd via eclipse IDE.
I have looked the documentation and google around but was not able to find any link.

I am not able to start another post here so editing the same post with more details.

First of all the design discussion should not be happening at this place but I don't find the forums active, not sure why is it so.
I have been planning to develop the big data platform and it seems most of the features of the platform are covered in spring-xd hence I am evaluating if I could build the additional features on top of it. I have got few requirements as of now which I don't see in spring-xd

1) The platform should support hot deployment of modules which I don't find in sprind-xd at least I could not see it from the docs and I tried to update the xml's in the module expecting the deployment trace appearing which did not. So I am assuming that there is not hot deployment feature right now, please confirm the same before I take a deep dive in the code.

2) How could I write a services which are not modules, may be some background jobs which will send the system information of the container or do some cleanup, I can write it as the job but I think appropriate term would be a service as it does not do any ETL stuff, it is plain service. What is the recommended way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Creating modules doesn't require restarting the node or the shell. You simply create the folder structure, as per the documentation, change the configuration as you see fit and when you create the new sink/source/processor it will be picked up automatically. From the documentation: "Using the default server configuration, you simply drop your module file into the modules directory and deploy a stream to the server."

Comment: I already could make that the manual process of deployment has to be triggered, it doesn't auto hot deploy. I think we could write a service which will call undeploy/deploy when the file changes in the module happen, not sure if that is in the roadmap of xd.

Answer (score 1):

2) How could I write a services which are not modules, may be some background jobs which will send the system information of the container or do some cleanup, I can write it as the job but I think appropriate term would be a service as it does not do any ETL stuff, it is plain service. What is the recommended way to do so?

XD supports an extensions mechanism which allows you to add any spring configuration to an XD container, either using @Configuration, or XML or groovy bean definitions. Basically you create a jar with your custom bean definitions, etc. install it in $XD_HOME/lib and configure XD with base package names to use for component scanning, or the base resource location (default is META-INF/spring-xd/ext). Extending XD is described in detail in the XD documentation.